# Django Custom User and problems with the admin page

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Im using Django 1.6 and I created a custom user and a custom manager just like that:

```
class MyManager(BaseUserManager): #create_user, create_superuser
    def _create_user(self, username, dni, password, is_staff, is_superuser, **extra_dields):
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Debes ingresar un Username')
        #Hace referencia al usuario personalizado de abajo
        user = self.model(username=username, dni=dni, is_active=True, is_staff=is_staff, is_superuser=is_superuser, **extra_dields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user

    #El manager para crear un usuario sin permisos
    def create_user(self, username, dni, password=None, **extra_dields):
        return self._create_user(username, dni, password, False, False, **extra_dields)

    #El manafer para crear usuarios con permisos
    def create_superuser(self, username, dni, password, **extra_dields):
        return self._create_user(username, dni, password, True, True, **extra_dields)

class Usuario(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    dni             = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
    username        = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=100)
    nombre          = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    appelidos       = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    is_active       = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff        = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    objects         = MyManager()

    #Campo con el que se va a identificar en el sistema
    USERNAME_FIELD  = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['dni']
```

Im having some problemas with runing the "admin" page in my localhost/admin and says that

NotImplementedError at /admin/

Do you have any idea of what could be happening? =)

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation [Custom users and `django.contrib.admin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-users-and-django-contrib-admin), to work with admin site, you need to define `has_perm` and `has_module_perms` methods.

Also, you need to define and register model admin class as explained in the doc.